# Is there a way to make a line break in an alert displayed by Shortcuts?

Tags: shortcuts-app

So I want to display an alert that has line breaks in it. All methods I tried, which include `\n`, <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> and `<br>` have not worked. The method provided should work on both desktop and mobile.

So if I do something like this:

[image]

It just displays it as pure text:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way is to store the text you want to display in a `text`-action where line breaks are easily storable.

[image: Image on how to do this]

Shows:

[image]

Comment: Thanks to this answer, I realize that you can also include “nothing” in that text box but actually just hit the return key twice. Then insert that Text as a variable in a Regex replace to get the equivalent of `\n\n`